# if statment in flutter future builder accept just =

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, null

```
 FutureBuilder(
      future: getData,
      builder: (BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        var sn = snapshot.data;
        var tp1 = snapshot.data[0]["currentprice"];
        var ent = snapshot.data[0]["entryprice"];
        Color col = Colors.blue;
        if (ent > tp1) {
          col = Colors.red;
        } else {
          col = Colors.grey;
        }
```

**the if statment work just with = condition and when i use > keep running this error

> Class 'String' has no instance method '>'.
> Receiver: "1"
> Tried calling: >("1.25454")

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `String` values to `double`

```
      FutureBuilder(
          future: getData,
          builder: (BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            var sn = snapshot.data;
          //convert your String to double
            var tp1 = double.parse(snapshot.data[0]["currentprice"]);
            var ent = double.parse(snapshot.data[0]["entryprice"]);
            Color col = Colors.blue;
            if (ent > tp1) {
              col = Colors.red;
            } else {
              col = Colors.grey;
            }
           });
```

Comment: just face another problem i want to replace int with index just like that   var tp1 = double.parse(snapshot.data[index]["currentprice"]);

Comment: how can do that

Answer (score 0):

Either `ent` or `tp1` is a String. Remember that the `>` operator only works with doubles and integers. So what you can do is to parse that String as a double or int and then proceed to the rest of the operation. Like this:

```
double.parse(ent);

int.parse(tp1);
```

And then, it will work just fine! :)